# How do I have automatic encrypted backups?

Tags: linux, ios, backup

I have a jailbroken iPhone, 2 Laptops, and another server.     I will set up these devices to backup files to a main backup server I have but I'm wondering how I can have this done automatically while having them stored encrypted/securely.  This backup server is a Netbook running Debian Wheezy and is also sharing my printer on the LAN via CUPS.  The Laptops run Arch Linux and Debian Wheezy. The iPhone has iOS 7.1.2.   I'd like to backup my photos and other important files but make it harder for someone with direct or remote access to see and do anything with the files.  I was thinking of rsync for initial automatic transfer of my backup but I'm not sure how to have it encrypted on the server automatically.